# How to update a dropdownlist inside an Ajax modal popup panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a girdview in side an update panel, the girdview allows to edit, delete the data in my database, I have button named Insert, when the insert button is clicked, an ajax model popup panel will show up, inside that pop up panel, there is a dropdownlist.

My question is that how can I update the dropdownlist inside the popup panel every time there is a change in my girdview panel.

I tried changing some data in the girdview, then I have to refresh the whole paper(thing which I don't want to do) to update the dropdownlist.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"  AutoEventWireup="true" 
 CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"   TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

  <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
```

```
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
 <asp:Button ID="RegisterButton" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="callmethod" />
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
 </asp:ScriptManager>
 <asp:Panel ID="MainPanel" runat="server" Style="display: none" CssClass="modalPopup">
      <div>
           <asp:Table ID="InputTable" runat="server">
                <asp:TableRow>
                     <asp:TableCell>
                          <asp:Label ID="LabelName" runat="server" Text="name">     </asp:Label>
                     </asp:TableCell>
                     <asp:TableCell>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                     </asp:TableCell>
                     <asp:TableCell>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NameRequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TName"
                               runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator">Cannot be Empty</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                     </asp:TableCell>
                     <asp:TableCell><asp:DropDownList ID="TProjectMID" runat="server">  </asp:DropDownList></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
           </asp:Table>
           <p style="text-align: center;">
                <asp:Button ID="OkButton" runat="server" Text="OK" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="OkButton_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
           </p>
      </div>
   </asp:Panel>
      <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="RegisterButton"
      BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID="MainPanel" OkControlID="OkButton"
      OnOkScript="onOk()" CancelControlID="CancelButton" PopupDragHandleControlID="InfoPanel" />
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePane" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProjectID" DataSourceID="DataSource"
                Width="921px">
                <Columns>
                     <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" CausesValidation="false"  causeValidation = "false"/>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ProjectID" SortExpression="ProjectID"
                          ReadOnly="True" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="ProjectName" SortExpression="ProjectName" />
                </Columns>
           </asp:GridView>
           <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
                DeleteCommand="DeleteProject" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                <DeleteParameters>
                     <asp:Parameter Name="original_ID" Type="String" />
                     <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
                </DeleteParameters>
           </asp:SqlDataSource>
      </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i've understood you. Why can't you bind the DropDownlist to it's DataSource every time the user clicks on the Insert-Button? You should also wrap the popup in an UpdatePanel and only `Update` it when the popup is shown, then only the popup will reload and not the whole page.

Comment: Clarification: You must not wrap the modal popup itself into an UpdatePanel but the whole content of the popup.

Comment: added these comments as answer.

Comment: I tried but not successful , the Insert button is registered with the modal popup of ajax control toolkit, I put the attribute onclick="callmethod" to the Insert button, then I put a break point at callmethod, run program in debug mode, and surprisingly, when Insert button is clicked, callmethod wasn't called :(

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically populate your dropdown list with AJAX. Or does .net have anyway you can bind a dropdown to a gridview. Last time i used it was 2.0. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you bind the DropDownlist to it's DataSource every time the user clicks on the Insert-Button? You should also wrap the content of the popup in its own UpdatePanel and only `Update` it when the popup is shown ot ensure that only the popup will be reloaded and not the whole page.

Edit:

The reason for the missing postback could be that any Validator is blocking it. Set `CausesValidation=false` to your Register-Button that opens the Popup. Another point: because the button is outside of the UpdatePanel `UpdatePane`, i would consider to create an [AsyncPostBacktrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx) with the `RegisterButton` as `ControlID`.

Comment: I tried but not successful , the Insert button is registered with the modal popup of ajax control toolkit, I put the attribute onclick="callmethod" to the Insert button, then I put a break point at callmethod, run program in debug mode, and surprisingly, when Insert button is clicked, callmethod wasn't called :(

Comment: @user: then i assume that you're rebinding the GridBiew on every postback and not only if `!Page.IsPostback`. That will prevent events from being triggered. You should show the relevant part of the code.